# Is it necessary that every statesman is a politician?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

I used to think that every statesman is a politician before coming across [this](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-politician-and-a-statesman/answer/Jonathan-James-3?srid=nGx9) post so I just wanted to clear that if there could be a statesman who is not a politician.

Comment: It depends on how you define them. Ordinarily, it's difficult to become a statesman without being a politician first, but I suppose you could say that Henry Kissinger is an example that shows it's possible.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Did you mean to write *“Is it necessary that every statesman* **BE** *a politician?”* I don’t understand your use of the indicative on a clause governed by necessity; that doesn’t scan for me.

Comment: Depends on your definitions for both terms.  There are people who are appointed to ambassador positions without ever having held a political office.

Comment: @tchrist BrE, and Englishes derived from it, have been drifting away from the mandative subjunctive (although there has been a marked revival in the last generation, possibly due to infuence from our old-fashioned US usage). I too am jarred by this when I encounter it in (for instance) the *Guardian*.

Comment: @tchrist - That was exactly what the OP meant in his question, I think this is a relevant mistake, he misused the usages of the indicative clause.

Answer (score 1):

A monarch may be considered as a statesman.  For example, George III was described by Beckles Wilson as ["a man, monarch, and statesman"](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/007685004) in the title of his 1907 biography of the late king.

However, it is necessary of (modern) monarchy that the monarch not play the role of a politician.

So I would say that it is not necessary that every statesman be a politician.

Answer (score 1):

The [definitions](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/statesman?s=t) of *statesman* are:

> 1. a person who is experienced in the art of government or versed in the administration of government affairs.
> 2. a person who exhibits great wisdom and ability in directing the affairs of a government or in dealing with important public issues.

While there may be exceptions, it's generally hard to achieve these without being politically savvy.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a statesman is a deceased or sometimes retired politician. It is a highly respectful term used only when the person in question is no longer in the public's eye. Thomas Brackett Reed, a former Speaker of the House, once said that "a statesman is a successful politician who is dead". Likewise, Harry S. Truman likened a statesman to "a politician who's been dead ten or fifteen years." A statesman, however, is not necessarily dead, though that is probably the most common variation. The Oxford English Dictionary defines a statesman as a "a skilled, experienced, and respected political leader or figure". Since a politician really isn't respected until she or he is dead, however, you could argue that a statesman is only a dead politician. Etymologically speaking, it is also clear that *statesman* is a portmanteau of *state* and *man*; a connection to the *state* is clearly a connection to politics. In any case, I think the answer to your question is apparent; to be a dead politician (our definition of statesman) you first and foremost must be a politician. Ergo, a statesman must be a politician, but not vice versa (if the politician is not respected or dead).

Comment: Saying that a statesman is a politician who's dead is an old joke, not meant as an actual definition. It basically refers to the fact that people (esp. other politicians) are reluctant to give such praise to leaders during their tenure, but are more willing in hindsight. See http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2010/04/statesman-is-politician-whos-been-dead.html.

Comment: In any case, I was proving a connection between a statesman and politics...